# Logging into circle pay via curl request

Tags: php, curl, automation, bots

I am trying create a script which logs into my pay.circle (Circle Pay's website) account in PHP via Curl. I am having issues as the response from submitting the POST request is a 502 bad gateway message.

I am not sure if I have found the correct URL for the login submission, I have used chromes inspector to find the url, see below:
[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SLnIH.png)

Is the URL perhaps not correct or am i not passing the correct data? See my code below:

```
$data = array(
        "email" => "skyrocket@yahoo.com",
        "password" => "test"
        );
    $fields = json_encode($data); 

$ch = curl_init();

$url = "https://api.circle.com/api/v2/customers/0/sessions";

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, "cookies/logins/cookies.txt");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, "cookies/logins/cookies.txt");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 40000);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_REFERER, "https://pay.circle.com/signin");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/72.0.3626.109 Safari/537.36");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, TRUE);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, TRUE);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $fields);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "POST");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER,  array(
'Accept: application/json, text/plain, */*',
'Origin: https://pay.circle.com',
'X-App-Version: ff40150fdea82e0f0cca84b649cabc06cc2955d3',
'X-Device-Id: {"fingerprint":"6c771befbe38d8a345506707ec6003a9","fingerprintVersion":"1.1.0","fingerprintCookie":"3d60faa3-1a9c-417f-8f3f-cf3545deb7f8"}',  
'X-ECP-Session-Id: 0000188520190305114719162707',                                                                   
'Content-Type: application/json;charset=UTF-8',                                                                                
'Content-Length: ' . strlen($fields)) );
$output = curl_exec($ch);
```

I have tried a variety of things as seen above, such as sending the post data as json. Or using the http build function to encode the text.

Any directions would be appreciated

Comment: are you sure the website is `pay.circle` ? because according to GoogleDNS, that domain does not exist: https://i.imgur.com/MVSAIcr.png

Comment: ... the domain `pay.circle` does not exist, but the domain `pay.circle.com` DOES exist, i guess you mean `pay.circle.com` ?

Answer (score 0):

<strike>(this is not a full solution on how to log in, but you did too many mistakes to simply add it as comment text, so i'll add my complaints as an `answer` instead..)</strike>

1: this website use cookies for login sessions, you need to fetch a cookie (with a simple GET request) before logging in, you didn't.

2: you're trying to send the username and password encoded in `multipart/form-data`-format (which is what you get if you give an array to `CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS`), but this website use JSON to log in, so you need to send the username and password json-encoded.

3: you need to send an OPTIONS request to api.circle.com/api/v2/customers/0/sessions with a valid cookie before attempting to log in, but you didn't.

4: this website uses a variation of a CSRF token here called `X-ECP-Session-Id` which you receive together with the GET request where you get the cookie, which you need to add to the login request, but you never fetched the token in the first place.

4: this website requires several custom http headers for the login request which you didn't add, specifically `Accept: application/json, text/plain, */*` and `Content-Type: application/json;charset=UTF-8` and `X-App-Id` and `X-App-Version` and `X-Device-Id` and finally the CSRF token `X-ECP-Session-Id` - you didn't add any of them.

no wonder your login request didn't succeed.

here's a login example using [hhb_curl](https://github.com/divinity76/hhb_.inc.php/blob/master/hhb_.inc.php):

```
<?php 
declare (strict_types = 1);
require_once('hhb_.inc.php');
const USERNAME = '???';
const PASSWORD = '???';
$hc = new hhb_curl('', true);
//now to fetch the csrf token and cookies
$html = $hc->exec('https://pay.circle.com/signin')->getStdOut();
{
    // we need stuff from the headers
    $cookies_raw = $hc->getResponseHeaders();
    $cookies_parsed = array();
    foreach ($cookies_raw as $tmp) {
        if (false === strpos($tmp, ':')) {
            // don't need this header
            continue;
        }
        $tmp = explode(':', $tmp, 2);
        $cookies_parsed[trim($tmp[0])] = trim($tmp[1]);
    }
    // 'X-App-Version: ff40150fdea82e0f0cca84b649cabc06cc2955d3'
    // 'X-Device-Id: {"fingerprint":"aa1683cf1ce7dcca7a347b887747896b","fingerprintVersion":"1.1.0","fingerprintCookie":"6ad46a77-0c7e-4bd7-8570-1568f2ec8b9c"}',
    // 'X-ECP-Session-Id: 0000188520190306085938487417',
    //hhb_var_dump($cookies_parsed) & die();
    assert(isset($cookies_parsed['X-App-Version']));
    // TODO: X-Device-Id apparently comes from https://assets.circle.com/assets/javascripts/application-63066bd45540e4f6a74081aaaf96154f.js
    // assert(isset($cookies_parsed['X-Device-Id']));
    assert(isset($cookies_parsed['X-ECP-Session-Id']));
    $login_headers = array(
        'Content-Type: application/json;charset=utf-8',
        'X-App-Id: angularjs',
        'X-App-Version: ' . $cookies_parsed['X-App-Version'],
        // TODO: 'X-Device-Id: ' . $cookies_parsed['X-Device-Id'], 
        'X-ECP-Session-Id: ' . $cookies_parsed['X-ECP-Session-Id'],
    );
    //hhb_var_dump($login_headers) & die();
}

$domd = @DOMDocument::loadHTML($html);
// now do the OPTIONS request. we need to do it to log in, but it doesn't return any useful data.
$hc->setopt_array(array(
    CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => 'OPTIONS',
    CURLOPT_URL => 'https://api.circle.com/api/v2/customers/0/sessions',
    CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array(
        'Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8',
        'Access-Control-Request-Method: POST',
        'Access-Control-Request-Headers: content-type,x-app-id,x-app-version,x-device-id,x-ecp-session-id',
        'Origin: https://pay.circle.com',
    )
))->exec()->setopt(CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, null);
// now to do the actual login
$json = $hc->setopt_array(array(
    CURLOPT_URL => 'https://api.circle.com/api/v2/customers/0/sessions',
    CURLOPT_POST => 1,
    CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => json_encode(array('email' => USERNAME, 'password' => PASSWORD)),
    CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => $login_headers
))->exec()->getStdOut();
$parsed = json_decode($json, true);
// now to look for login errors
$login_errors = [];
/*
 {
    "response": {
        "status": {
            "code": 4,
            "customerState": {
                "isEmailVerified": false,
                "isMfaVerified": false
            }
        },
        "errors": {
            "emailOrPassword": ["invalid"]
        },
        "displayErrors": ["Email or password is incorrect"],
        "displayErrorsMap": {
            "emailOrPassword": "Email or password is incorrect"
        }
    }
}
 */
$response=$parsed['response'];
if(!empty($response['errors'])){
    $login_errors[]=$response['errors'];
}
if(!empty($response['displayErrors'])){
    $login_errors[]=$response['displayErrors'];
}
if(!empty($response['displayErrors'])){
    $login_errors[]=$response['displayErrorsMap'];
}
if(!empty($login_errors)){
    echo "LOGIN ERRORS!\n";
    var_dump($login_errors);
    throw new \RuntimeException("LOGIN ERRORS!");
}
var_dump($json);
```

which outputs:

```
$ php wtf2.php
LOGIN ERRORS!
array(3) {
  [0]=>
  array(1) {
    ["emailOrPassword"]=>
    array(1) {
      [0]=>
      string(7) "invalid"
    }
  }
  [1]=>
  array(1) {
    [0]=>
    string(30) "Email or password is incorrect"
  }
  [2]=>
  array(1) {
    ["emailOrPassword"]=>
    string(30) "Email or password is incorrect"
  }
}
PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught RuntimeException: LOGIN ERRORS! in /cygdrive/c/projects/misc/wtf2.php:94
Stack trace:
#0 {main}
  thrown in /cygdrive/c/projects/misc/wtf2.php on line 94
```

because `???` is not a valid username, see line 4 & 5.

Comment: Thanks alot for your response. I have edited my code in my question, i did add the custom headers too. can i please ask you check your discord? i sent you a friend request please sir

Comment: @Randell you need a minimum of 3 http requests to log in (the GET request for the cookies and CSRF token, the OPTIONS request, and the final login POST request), your code only issue 1 http request in total, so it's obviously incorrect. that said, re-read my post, i added a login example that i believe is fully functional